# Using the Weierstrass Preparation Theorem on $y^2-xy^2-xy$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, complex-analysis, algebraic-geometry

I am stuck trying to solve exercise 2.6.7 of the book *Singular points of plane curves* by C.T.C. Wall.
The exercise asks to find the Weierstrass decomposition of $y^2-xy^2-xy$ in the form $U(x,y)(y^2+ya_1(x)+a_2(x)$.
The book uses the notation $P_s(y,\lambda)=y^s+\sum_{i=1}^{s}\lambda_i y^{s-i}$ with $\lambda=(\lambda_1,...,\lambda_s)$ and so will I. 
So far I did the following.

Compute $P_2(y,\lambda)=y^2+\lambda_1y+\lambda_2=(y-\alpha)(y-\beta)$.

I want to use the division theorem on $F(x,y,\lambda)=y^2-x^2-xy$ i.e. I want to find the unique holomorphic functions $Q,A_i$ such that
$F(x,y,\lambda)=P_s(y,\lambda)Q(x,y,\lambda)+R(x,y,\lambda)$ 
with $R(x,y,\lambda)=\sum_{i=1}^{s}A_i(x,\lambda)y^{s-i}$.

Therefore define
$Q(x,y,\lambda)=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\oint \frac{F(x,y,\lambda)}{(z-y)P_s(z,\lambda)}dz=\frac{y^2-xy^2-xy}{(y-\alpha)(y-\beta)}+\frac{\alpha^2-x\alpha^2-x\alpha}{(\alpha-y)(\alpha-\beta)}+\frac{\beta^2-x\beta^2-x\beta}{(y-\beta)(\alpha-\beta)}$.

We also compute, using
$A_i(x,\lambda)=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\oint\frac{P_{i-1}(z,\lambda)F(x,y,\lambda)}{P_s(z,\lambda)}$, that

$A_1(x,\lambda)=\frac{\alpha^2-x\alpha^2-x\alpha}{\alpha-\beta}+\frac{\beta^2-x\beta^2-x\beta}{\beta-\alpha}$
and
$A_2(x,\lambda)=\frac{-\beta}{\alpha-\beta}(\alpha^2-x\alpha^2-x\alpha)+\frac{\alpha}{\alpha-\beta}(\beta^2-x\beta^2-x\beta)$.

Now I need to use the Implicit function theorem to find holomorphic functions $x\mapsto H_i(x)$ such that for $H=(H_1,H_2)$ we have $A_1(x,H(x))=0$ and $A_2(x,H(x))=0$. However I cannot seem to work this out.

Does someone know how to proceed and am I correct that substituting $H_i$ for $\lambda_i$ in $Q$ and $P_s$ will end the exercise (meaning that $y^2-xy^2-xy=Q(x,y,H(x))P_s(y,H(x))$). Thank you for your help!

Comment: Isn't $y^2-xy^2-xy$  just, $(1-x)y(y-(1-x)^{-1}x)$?

Comment: Yes, I think you are right. Thank you! Do you know of some kind of method or algorithm that you can use to find this decomposition in general?